# In Hyperledger Fabric, how are the certificates for the TLS messaging layer generated?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

It seems to say in the docs that they are generated by a root CA (https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release/gossip.html) but what does that mean for node discovery, that is Gossip?

I think the hole in my understanding is whether you need to be part of a channel to actually see other nodes in that channel (in which case I understand certification is handled by the `fabric-ca-server` on the MSP on the channel, although this may be incorrect).

However that begs the question of how you join an existing node to a channel if you can't discover it, so in addition how does that work?

Answer (score 0):

TLS certificates have nothing to do with node discovery. Node discovery is all about endpoints.

To join a node to a channel, you give it a genesis block (or, a config block in case you bootstrap from a snapshot).

The genesis block (or a config block) contains endpoints (host:port) of the anchor peers of the channel.

The peer that joins the channel simply contacts the anchor peers, and exchanges membership information with them.

Another way of connecting to other peers, is via the bootstrap peer set found in the local configuration. This is a set of endpoints a peer has predefined and these endpoints should only point to peers in the same organization as the peer.

> I think the hole in my understanding is whether you need to be part of
> a channel to actually see other nodes in that channel

Yes and no. If you have peers in your organization that know you, they will send channel metadata messages (but not blocks in that channel) to you.
Only if you have joined the channel (received a genesis block / config block of that channel from your local admin) then you will also start sending channel metadata messages to other peers in the channel.